# Individual Hub onDisconnect

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I have 1 `SignalR` connection and 2 `Hubs`, `ChatHub` & `OnlineHub`.

I have been researching on how to `OnConnect` & `OnDisconnect` for each `Hub`.
Currently when I start a connection to server, both `ChatHub` and `OnlineHub` 's will run their `OnConnected()`. Is there anyway I can separate them?

```
$.connection.hub.url = chatHubUrl;
var chat = $.connection.ChatHub;
var onlinehub = $.connection.OnlineHub;

$.connection.hub.start({ withCredentials: false }).done(function () {
    onlinehub.server.connectGlobalConnection(userId, token).done(function () {});
});

[HubName("OnlineHub")]
public class OnlineHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "Online");
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}

[HubName("ChatHub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

What I am asking was, can each hub act as a single connection?

Let's say `ChatHub` from URL-Chat, `OnlineHub` from URL-Online.

So I can easily detect their `OnConnect` & `OnDisconnect`

Comment: check this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

Answer (score 0):

No. See the relevant docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#multiplehubs).

Specifically:

> You can define multiple Hub classes in an application. When you do
>   that, the connection is shared but groups are separate.